# Sending messages between clients socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm working on a chat application and using `socket.io` / `node` for that. Basically I came up with the following strategies:

1. Send message from the client which is received by the socket server which then sends it to the receiving client. On the background I store that to the message on the DB to be retrieved later if the user wishes to seee his old conversations.

The **pros** of this approach is that the user gets the message almost instantly since we don't wait for the DB operation to complete, but the **con** is that if the DB operation failed and exactly that time the client refreshed its page to fetch the message, it won't get that.

2. Send message form the client to the server, the server then stores it on the DB first and then only sends it to the receiving client.

The **pros** is that we make sure that the message will be received to the client only if its stored in the DB. The **con** is that it will be no way close to real time since we'll be doing a DB operation in between slowing down the message passing.

3. Send message to the client which then is stored on a cache layer(redis for example) and then instantly broadcast it to the receiving client. On background keep fetching records from redis and updating DB. If the client  refreshes the page, we first look into the DB and then the redis layer.

The **pros** is that we make the communication faster and also make sure messages are presented correctly on demand. The **con** is that this is quite complex as compared to above implementations, and I'm wondering if there's any easier way to achieve this?

My question is whats the way to go if you're building a serious chat application that ensures both - faster communication and data persistence.  What are some strategies that app like facebook, whatsapp etc. use for the same? I'm not looking for exact example, but a few pointers will help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the option number 2. I've been doing myself Chat apps in node and I found out that this is the best option. Saving in a database takes few milliseconds, which includes the 0.x milliseconds to write in the databse and the few milliseconds of latency in communication ( https://blog.serverdensity.com/mongodb-benchmarks/ ).

SO I would consider this approach realtime. The good thing with this is that if it fails, you can display a message to the sender that it failed, for whatever reason.

Facebook, whatsapp and many other big messaging apps are based on XMPP (jabber) which is a very, very big protocol for instant messaging and everything is very well documented on how to do things but it is based in XML, so you still have to parse everything etc but luckily there are very good libraries to handle with xmpp. So if you want to go the common way, using XMPP you can, but most of the big players in this area are not following anymore all the standards, since does not have all the features we are used to use today.

I would go with doing my own version, actually, I already something made (similar to slack), if you want I could give you access to it in private.

So to end this, number 2 is the way to go (for me). XMPP is cool but brings also a lot of complexity.